# Won't loop nor run the second function when needed

Tags: python

I'm a beginner who's learning to program in Python and I've ran into this problem. I tried searching for an answer, but I didn't really know what to search for.

Why does my function keep executing 'else', even when I enter a number lower than 150 when asked? It should, instead, run a second function called 'wish_second()', but for some reason it ignores it.

Originally my plan was to get the first function to activate 'else' only when writing a large number, but now it seems to keep on doing that with small numbers and even when writing something like 'asd', when instead it should keep on asking for a valid number.

```
def wish_first():

    print "You decide that you will first wish for gold coins. "
    print "How many coins will you wish for? "

    while True:

        next = raw_input("> ")

        try:
            how_much = int(next)

        except ValueError:
            print "Learn to write a number!"

        if next < 150:
            print "You fill your pockets and think of a second wish. "
            wish_second()

        else:
            dead("A bunch of coins fall on your head and you die.")

def wish_second():

    print "You can't decide what you want to wish for. "
    print "You're debating wheter to get home or wish for a unicorn. "
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't keep asking for a number after you enter an invalid string like 'asd', because there is nothing in the `except` block to make it skip the rest of the code and go back to the start of the `while True` loop. So, it correctly enters the code in `except`, printing out the error message, but then just goes along to the next line which is the comparison.

One way to solve that would be to add the rest of the code inside the `try` block, so that it is only executed if the input was a number. For example (note, I have also changed the comparison, as mentioned in the other answers):

```
def wish_first():

    print "You decide that you will first wish for gold coins. "
    print "How many coins will you wish for? "

    while True:

        next = raw_input("> ")

        try:
            how_much = int(next)

            if how_much < 150:
                print "You fill your pockets and think of a second wish. "
                wish_second()

            else:
                dead("A bunch of coins fall on your head and you die.")

        except ValueError:
            print "Learn to write a number!"
```

Comment: Thank you very much! This fixed my problem and it now works as intended. :)

Answer (score 2):

You are converting to an int, but never using that variable

```
how_much = int(next)
```

But your comparison is against a string - `if next < 150:`

Change your comparison to use `how_much`. You can also do this: `next = int(raw_input("> "))`

Comment: after doing this I now run into an error which I faced before: UnboundLocalError: local variable 'how_much' referenced before assignment. Any idea why it's doing this? I tried researching about it, but only answers I saw said it happens when the variable with which I'm working with is outside a function, but in my case that doesn't seem to be the issue.

Comment: I'm guessing your `except` statement is printing in those cases, correct? Assuming that's true, it's because you assign `how_much` in your `try`, but if that statement fails, you don't create the variable in your `except`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert to the input value to an `int`

```
next = int(raw_input("> "))
```

Otherwise you are comparing a `string` to an `int` here

```
if next < 150:
```

As pointed out by @davidism, you may also use your variable `how_much` since you converted it to an `int` already

```
how_much = int(next)
```

So you could say

```
if how_much < 150:
```